# Nest.js get injector instance

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I want to create an instance of a dynamically loaded class trough Nest.js dependency injection service.

In Angular I would use `Injector.create`, what would be the equivalent in Nest.js ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First of all you should get a ModuleRef which references current module, and then use its "get" method to get an instance.

```
@Injectable()
export class AppletService {
  files: FileService;

  constructor(
    private moduleRef: ModuleRef,
  ) { 
    this.files = moduleRef.get(FileService);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is posible get a instance service like AppConfigService in a static method ?

Comment: @Hector i have the same question.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69572752/how-to-use-winston-logger-in-nest-node-in-static-classes

Comment: using `moduleRef.get` on `constructor`'s isn't safe. Move it to `onModuleInit` method instead