# In Nest.js, how to get a service instance inside a decorator?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, nestjs, typescript-decorator

In `CustomDecorator`, how to access a service instance defined in Nest.js?

```
export const CustomDecorator = (): MethodDecorator => {
  return (
    target: Object,
    propertyKey: string | symbol,
    descriptor: PropertyDescriptor
    ) => {

    // Here, is possibile to access a Nest.js service (i.e. TestService) instance?

    return descriptor;
  }
};
```

Comment: Have you found a better solution so far?

Answer (score 45):

Late to the party, but since I had a similar problem ([Use global nest module in decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60578332/use-global-nest-module-in-decorator/60608856#60608856)) and stumbled upon this question.

```
import { Inject } from '@nestjs/common';
export function yourDecorator() {
  const injectYourService = Inject(YourServiceClass);

  return (target: any, propertyKey: string, propertyDescriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => {
    // this is equivalent to have a constructor like constructor(yourservice: YourServiceClass)
    // note that this will injected to the instance, while your decorator runs for the class constructor
    injectYourService(target, 'yourservice');

    // do something in you decorator

    // we use a ref here so we can type it
    const yourservice: YourServiceClass = this.yourservice;
    yourservice.someMethod(someParam);
  };
}
```

Comment: What if there is already an instance with the name ? Basically if I use decorator multiple times on same service but different functions. I tried and it doesn't throw errors but is there a side-effect.

Answer (score 23):

We have a few point:

- Property decorator executed before `decorated instance` will be created.
- Decorator want to use `some instance` resolved by Injector of `decorated instance`.

As a straightforward way - use `some instance` injected by `decorated instance`.

```
@Injectable()
export class CatsService {
  constructor(public myService: MyService){}

  @CustomDecorator()
  foo(){}
}

export const CustomDecorator = (): MethodDecorator => {
  return (
    target: Object,
    propertyKey: string | symbol,
    descriptor: PropertyDescriptor
  ) => {

    const originalMethod = descriptor.value;

    descriptor.value = function () {
      const serviceInstance = this;
      console.log(serviceInstance.myService);

    }

    return descriptor;
  }
};
```

PS i think it is [somehow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49031159/nest-js-get-injector-instance?rq=1) possible to use instance of Injector to get any of desired instances (like [angular does](https://angular.io/api/core/Injector#get)).

Comment: Good idea, byt not exactly what I want. I need service instance in `CustomDecorator`, without the need for `CatService` to inject `MyService`. That is, `MyService` should be injected only in my decorator (where I put those comments).

Comment: Good workaround, but I am struggling with this as well. Eventually I need a way to inject and `MyService` only in the decorator.

Comment: @buggy
One question: So this `originalMethod` is actually the `foo()` where the decorator is applied? 
Can I able to call this originalMethod inside this decorator? Something like:
1. Do some pre-processing  2. Call the originalMethod 3. Do some book-keeping

Is this possible to be in this method decorator?

Answer (score 16):

Came across this question and spent the day trying to figure out a good answer. This may not fit every use case, but I was able to copy a common pattern in Nest's core package to suit my needs.

I wanted to create my own decorator for annotating controller methods to handle events (e.g, `@Subscribe('some.topic.key') async handler() { ... })`).

To implement this, my decorator used `SetMetadata` from `@nestjs/common` to register some metadata I required (the method name it was being applied to, the class it belonged to, a reference to the method).

```
export const Subscribe = (topic: string) => {
  return (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => {
    SetMetadata<string, RabbitSubscriberMetadataConfiguration>(
      RABBITMQ_SUBSCRIBER,
      {
        topic,
        target: target.constructor.name,
        methodName: propertyKey,
        callback: descriptor.value,
      },
    )(target, propertyKey, descriptor);
  };
};
```

From there, I was able to create my own module which hooked into Nest's lifecycle hooks to find all methods I had decorated with my decorator, and apply some logic to it, e.g:

```
@Module({
  imports: [RabbitmqChannelProvider],
  providers: [RabbitmqService, MetadataScanner, RabbitmqSubscriberExplorer],
  exports: [RabbitmqService],
})
export class RabbitmqModule implements OnModuleInit {
  constructor(
    private readonly explorer: RabbitmqSubscriberExplorer,
    private readonly rabbitmqService: RabbitmqService,
  ) {}

  async onModuleInit() {
    // find everything marked with @Subscribe
    const subscribers = this.explorer.explore();
    // set up subscriptions
    for (const subscriber of subscribers) {
      await this.rabbitmqService.subscribe(
        subscriber.topic,
        subscriber.callback,
      );
    }
  }
}
```

The explorer service used some utilities in `@nestjs/core` to introspect the container and handle finding all the decorated functions with their metadata.

```
@Injectable()
export class RabbitmqSubscriberExplorer {
  constructor(
    private readonly modulesContainer: ModulesContainer,
    private readonly metadataScanner: MetadataScanner,
  ) {}

  public explore(): RabbitSubscriberMetadataConfiguration[] {
    // find all the controllers
    const modules = [...this.modulesContainer.values()];
    const controllersMap = modules
      .filter(({ controllers }) => controllers.size > 0)
      .map(({ controllers }) => controllers);

    // munge the instance wrappers into a nice format
    const instanceWrappers: InstanceWrapper<Controller>[] = [];
    controllersMap.forEach(map => {
      const mapKeys = [...map.keys()];
      instanceWrappers.push(
        ...mapKeys.map(key => {
          return map.get(key);
        }),
      );
    });

    // find the handlers marked with @Subscribe
    return instanceWrappers
      .map(({ instance }) => {
        const instancePrototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(instance);
        return this.metadataScanner.scanFromPrototype(
          instance,
          instancePrototype,
          method =>
            this.exploreMethodMetadata(instance, instancePrototype, method),
        );
      })
      .reduce((prev, curr) => {
        return prev.concat(curr);
      });
  }

  public exploreMethodMetadata(
    instance: object,
    instancePrototype: Controller,
    methodKey: string,
  ): RabbitSubscriberMetadataConfiguration | null {
    const targetCallback = instancePrototype[methodKey];
    const handler = Reflect.getMetadata(RABBITMQ_SUBSCRIBER, targetCallback);
    if (handler == null) {
      return null;
    }
    return handler;
  }
}
```

I am not espousing this as being the best way to handle this, but it has worked well for me. Use this code at your own risk, it should get you started :-). I adapted the code available from here: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/5.1.0-stable/packages/microservices/listener-metadata-explorer.ts

Comment: Thank you for sharing. I need to do the same. (Schedule repeatable tasks, in this case).

Comment: I discovered https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nestjs-plus/discovery, which was helpful.

Comment: I work with the maintainer of that library, glad you found it ;)

Comment: Cool, I made a suggestion there with regards to caching.

Answer (score 1):

I got inspiration from [Buggy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52272311/4640909) and [florian norbert bepunkt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60608920/4640909). I have created a decorator that injects the service only in the decorator if it is not available in the target.

```
function CustomDecorator(): MethodDecorator {
  return (target: object, propertyKey: string | symbol, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => {
    const originalMethod = descriptor.value;

    descriptor.value = function (...args: any[]) {
      const servicesContainer = {};

      let myServiceInstance = (this as any).myService;

      if (!myServiceInstance) {
        const injectMyService = Inject(MyService);        
        injectMyService(servicesContainer, 'myService');
        myServiceInstance = (servicesContainer as any).myService;
      }

      
      myServiceInstance.someMethod();

      originalMethod.call(this, ...args);
    };
  };
}
```

Answer (score -15):

I was trying to use my config service inside a ParamDecorator, so I access my service by creating a new instance of it :

```
export const MyParamDecorator = createParamDecorator((data, req) => {

  // ...
  const configService = new ConfigService(`${process.env.NODE_ENV || 'default'}.env`);
  const myConfigValue = configService.getMyValue();
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Creating a new instance of an @Injectable service class in nest.js is bad-practice and should be avoided