# How to inject configService value to FilesInterceptor in NestJS?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, nest

Hi I want to write the API to upload the file using @UseInterceptors. I cannot inject the configService value inside it. Below is my example code,

```
  constructor(
    configService: ConfigService,
  ) {}

  @Post('product/image/:brandNo')
  @UseInterceptors(
    FilesInterceptor('files', 2, {
      storage: diskStorage({
        destination: (req, file, cb) => {
          const brandNo = req.params.brandNo;
          const directory = `../${this.configService.get('BASE_PATH_FILE')}/${brandNo}/product/image`;
          if (!fs.existsSync(directory)) {
            fs.mkdirSync(directory, { recursive: true });
          }
          cb(null, directory);
        },
        filename: function (req, file, callback) {
          callback(null, file.originalname);
        },
      }),
    }),
  )
```

As you can see from the code, the

> ${this.configService.get('BASE_PATH_FILE')}

is not working here. How can I inject it ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to use `this` inside TS decorator ! But it's technically possible to inject `configService` inside decorator.
You can check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/60608920/10208733

Try this :

```js
import { Inject } from '@nestjs/common';

export const destinationFunc = (req, file, cb) => {
  const configService = Inject(ConfigService);
  const brandNo = req.params.brandNo;
  
  const directory = `../${configService.get('BASE_PATH_FILE')}/${brandNo}/product/image`;
  if (!fs.existsSync(directory)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(directory, { recursive: true });
  }
  cb(null, directory);
}


@UseInterceptors(
  FilesInterceptor('files', 2, {
    storage: diskStorage({
      destination: destinationFunc,
      filename: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, file.originalname);
      },
    }),
  }),
)
```